# how to add XElement in specific location in XML Document

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I want to create an XML document like this:

[image: Xml Doc]

I want to create it from scratch using code and LINQ-to-XML. In the form Load Event I've written this code:

```
private void Form9_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"));
    XElement myroot = new XElement("Employees");
    doc.Add(myroot);
}
```

How I can add new person to Employees, and if I want to insert person in specific location what can I do?

How I can delete or update a specific person ?

Answer (score 38):

Search element you want to add and use Add method as shown below

```
xDoc.Element("content")
    .Elements("item")
    .Where(item => item.Attribute("id").Value == "2").FirstOrDefault()
    .AddAfterSelf(new XElement("item", "C", new XAttribute("id", "3")));
```

or

```xml
<Microsoft>
<DOTNet>

</DOTNet>
</Microsoft>
```

```
private void addToXml()
{
    XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("yourfile.xml");

    xmlDoc.Element("Microsoft").Add(new XElement("DOTNet", new XElement("Name", "Nisar"),
        new XElement("Forum", "dotnetobject"), new XElement("Position", "Member")));

    xmlDoc.Save("yourfile.xml");
    readXml();
}
```

```xml
<Microsoft>
<DOTNet>
  <Name>Nisar</Name>
  <Forum>dotnetobject</Forum>
  <Position>Member</Position>
</DOTNet>
</Microsoft>
```