# Is it possible to convert this foreach loop into a LINQ-to-XML loop?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml, xelement

I originally asked this question ([Can we automatically add a child element to an XElement in a sortable manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70706705/2287576)) and it was closed as a duplicate ([how to add XElement in specific location in XML Document](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5725720/2287576)).

This is teh code that I have at the moment:

```
bool bInserted = false;
foreach (var weekDB in xdoc.Root.Elements())
{
    DateTime datWeekDB = DateTime.ParseExact(weekDB.Name.LocalName, "WyyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    if (datWeekDB != null && datWeekDB.Date > historyWeek.Week.Date)
    {
        // Insert here
        weekDB.AddBeforeSelf(xmlHistoryWeek);
        bInserted = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!bInserted)
    xdoc.Root.Add(xmlHistoryWeek);
```

It works fine. But I wondered if I can use LINQ to acheive the same thing? The linked answer suggests:

> Search element you want to add and use Add method as shown below
>
> ```
> xDoc.Element("content")
>     .Elements("item")
>     .Where(item => item.Attribute("id").Value == "2").FirstOrDefault()
>     .AddAfterSelf(new XElement("item", "C", new XAttribute("id", "3")));
> ```

But I don't understand how to end up with logic like that based on my codes logic.

Comment: I should note something: I copied your condition logic into my answer directly so you can see how it relates. However, you should be aware that `datWeekDB` can't be null. Rather, `ParseExact` will throw an exception if the value to parse is invalid.

Comment: @JackA. Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to think about it is: you are going to use LINQ to find a specific element. Then you will insert into the document based on what you found.

So something like this:

```
var targetElement = xdoc.Root.Elements()
    .Where(weekDB => {
        DateTime datWeekDB = DateTime.ParseExact(weekDB.Name.LocalName, "WyyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return datWeekDB != null && datWeekDB.Date > historyWeek.Week.Date;
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
if (targetElement == null)
{
    xdoc.Root.Add(xmlHistoryWeek);
}
else
{
    targetElement.AddBeforeSelf(xmlHistoryWeek);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate you slotting it in like that. So from your original comment it is safe to simply remove the `datWeekDB != null` bit. I'll test this tomorrow.

Comment: I confirm that it is working correctly. Thanks again.